# Spring Kafka : How to prevent from partition revococation when processing long time jobs

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I would like to ask, if there is any way to prevent consumer from being revoked when processing long time operation using @KafkaListener?

I have an application where there are jobs which takes a lot of time to process (30-60 minutes) and currently max.poll.interval.ms is set to 90 minutes. When new instance of application appears, there is rebalancing and if there are actaully processing jobs, messages from other partitions are suspended (because partitions/groups are revoked). Is there any way to still process new messages by consumer even if topic is rebalancing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka is not really designed for such scenarios.

However, you can set `max.poll.records` to `1`, and `pause()` the container when you receive a record.

Hand off the processing to another thread and exit the listener; the container will continue to poll the broker while processing, but returning no records. When processing is complete, acknowledge the record (use `AckMode.MANUAL`), to commit its offset, and `resume()` the container.

If a rebalance occurs while processing, the container will re-pause the consumer.

If you want to commit the offset before processing (risking record loss), you don't need manual acks.